# Bootup error: grub rescue> unknown file system

Tags: windows

Previously, my system had Windows 7 on it. I wanted to try Ubuntu so I created a new 30GB partition in the H: drive in Windows 7 and installed Ubuntu in that (but the partition didn't show up in Windows). I then formatted my H: drive. Now I am getting the error: grub rescue> unknown file system.

If I use the "ls" command at the GRUB command prompt, I get
`(hd0) (hd0,msdos11)  (hd0,msdos10) (hd0,msdos9) (hd0,msdos8) (hd0,msdos7) (hd0,msdos6)(hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)  (fd0)`

Comment: use this -http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, why did you format your H: drive? That had Ubuntu on it!
You can fix this by getting your Ubuntu CD, booting from it, and reinstalling Ubuntu on whatever partition you want to. This will also reinstall GRUB2 and therefore make your system able to boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 (which, by chance, is the system I use myself)

Hope this helps!
-whiskers75 :)